# What percentage of a complete Denisovan genomes lives on in the union of the sets of overlapping pieces in extant humans

Tags: genetics, dna, human-evolution, human-genome, anthropology

In studies like [this one mapping out distributions around the world](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2016.03.037) or the analysis described in [this article (suggesting a contribution from a non-Denisovan but Denisovan-like unidentified hominin to Melanesian populations](https://web.archive.org/web/20161022140459/https://www.sciencenews.org/article/dna-data-offer-evidence-unknown-extinct-human-relative), various single digit percentages are given of an average as high as 6%.

One complication in talking about this is what we mean by percent. Just through shared DNA we'd have over 99%, if we knew which DNA was shared. There are surely other complications, like how do you count repetitions toward the percentage, etc. But I mean to ask what percentage of  DNA that is DNA descended from introgressions adds up to, if you put together the different and overlapping pieces various people have.

I realize it may also be hard to pin down exactly what one would mean by a Denisovan genome -- as I said one of the linked articles suggests there may at least one Denisovan-*like* hominin species represented in the introgressions.

Note: [Someone already asked this about Neanderthals.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/how-much-of-the-neanderthal-genome-is-living-on-in-humans)